# Agora rtc - how to change playback audio device

Tags: agora.io, agora

I am working with angular and agoraRTC and I would like to change output device on click (like in this [example from webrtc](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)) .

I am getting a list of playback audio devices :

```
AgoraRTC.getPlaybackDevices()
```

but then I am wondering how is it possible to set playbackDevice to given deviceID ?

I was not able to find a proper method in agora documentation.

For microphone I was able to achieve the result with this:

```
this.microphoneAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
this.microphoneAudioTrack.setDevice(deviceId)
```